# Top and Bottom Padding issues on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile

I've been running into issues where I cannot scroll all the way up or down in one swipe on mobile. I'm assuming the issue has to do with a mix of the mobile navigation I created and the url bar on the phone showing and hiding depending on if you're scrolling up or down.

Has anyone run into this issue/found a working solution for it?

Comment: Making a `jsfiddle` or something would make helping you a lot easier.

Comment: It's a mobile only issue and it's likely that the issue won't be recreated anyways if I made a fiddle.

Comment: Well at least include some code? really hard to answer a question with literally nothing to go on...

Comment: I've set something minor up. http://magento.visualapp.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem disappeared when I changed two rules

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 850px)
body, html {
    min-height: 100vh;
    min-width: 100vw;
}
```

and

```
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

Just use min-height and min-width instead of declaring them explicitly.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure why it would be an issue on this specifically. We've had these styles for a while and haven't run into this issue before. Thanks I'll have to re-work our style sheet to address this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a set viewport?

If you're using something like

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

It could be affecting the way your phone natively scrolls.

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> is what I'm currently using.